# Excel formula for converting text which contains weeks and days into days

Tags: excel, function, date, time, formula

I want everything in days, assuming 1 week = 5 days. So I have the following data (also want to disregard > and < signs):

```
  1w 3d
> 1w 4d
> 1w 3.25d
< 2w 3.25d
> 1w 0.75d
< 4.25d
  0d
```

Would like the answer to look like:

```
8, Calculated like so --> ((1 week * 5) + 3 days)
9
8.25
13.25
5.75
4.25
0
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a formula approach:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("w",A1)-1),">",""),"<","")),0)*5 + TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("w",A1),0)+1,LEN(A1)),">",""),"<",""),"d",""))
```

[image]

---

EDIT

As per your comment this formula should deal with the issue.

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("w",A1)-1),">",""),"<","")),0)*5 + IFERROR(--TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("w",A1),0)+1,LEN(A1)),">",""),"<",""),"d","")),0)
```

Comment: @Gary'sStudent change your line to `xvert = Evaluate(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(sin, ">", ""), "<", ""), "d", ""), "w", "*5+"))` and it will deal with the `<` and `>`

Comment: I feel you answer is superior.

Comment: Only downfall: I get "#VALUE!" when the entry is "1w"... for whatever reason the 1w with no days throws that error (sorry I didn't provide that as an example, but I appreciate your time and effort!)

Comment: Any chance you would know how to do the same thing in python? I find it a more dynamic than excel, would be nice to do the same function in there.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following one-line User Defined Function:

```
Public Function xvert(sin As String) As Double
   While Not Left(sin, 1) Like "[0-9]"
       sin = Mid(sin, 2)
   Wend
   xvert = Evaluate(Replace(Replace(Replace(sin, " ", "+"), "d", ""), "w", "*5"))
End Function
```

[image]

The UDF works by converting the data into a formula and then evaluating the formula.  So:

3w 4.3d

is evaluated as:

=3*5 + 4.3

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

Macros must be enabled for this to work!